# Is it possible to download Appium v1.7.2 command line tools (CLI)?

Tags: appium, appium-ios, appium-android

Currently I'm using Appium Desktop v1.7.2 and manually starting the server before running the script. But now I have to start Appium server through code/program for v1.7.2 to do framework design. I came to know that Appium Desktop version cannot be started programmatcally(If I'm not wrong).

Anyone can let me know that, Is their Appium v1.7.2 CLI can be download/available? if yes, Any sample script would be great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my own Appium server utilities class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumDriverLocalService;
import io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumServiceBuilder;
import io.appium.java_client.service.local.flags.GeneralServerFlag;

/**
 * This class handles Appium Server
 * 
 * @author Bill Hileman
 */
public class AppiumServer {

    private AppiumDriverLocalService service;
    private AppiumServiceBuilder builder;
    private DesiredCapabilities cap;

    private int port = 4723;

    public void startServer() {
        // Set Capabilities
        cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability("noReset", "false");

        // Build the Appium service
        builder = new AppiumServiceBuilder();
        builder.withIPAddress("0.0.0.0");
        builder.usingPort(port);
        builder.withCapabilities(cap);
        builder.withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.SESSION_OVERRIDE);
        builder.withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.LOG_LEVEL, "error");

        // Start the server with the builder
        service = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(builder);
        service.start();
    }

    public void stopServer() {
        service.stop();
    }

    public boolean serverIsRunnning() {

        boolean isServerRunning = false;
        ServerSocket serverSocket;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // If control comes here, then it means that the port is in use
            isServerRunning = true;
        } finally {
            serverSocket = null;
        }
        return isServerRunning;
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you installed appium CLI using npm install appium@1.7.2 command?

Comment: Yes, that’s what I mean

Answer (score 0):

On mac:
`mkdir your_appium_dir` 
`cd your_appium_dir` 
`npm install appium@1.7.2` 
`cd appium`
`npm install` [this is to fetch the dependencies and download]

To start server manually:
`node .`
To start server programmatically: [Python code]
`p = subprocess.Popen('node .', cwd=your_appium_dir_path,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)`